# Is there any way in Highcharts to auto show Labels/Text on a scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like a scatter chart to be able to automatically show next to each PLOT point or BUBBLE, a piece of text identifying it.

[image: Here is an example of what i am trying to achieve]

Any Help would be very much appreciated !!

Answer (score 6):

You need the name in the data, and add a dataLabel in series, check this:

```
series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            x:40,
            formatter:function() {
                return this.point.name;
            },
            style:{color:"black"}
        },
        data: [{
            "x": 23,
            "y": 22,
            "z": 200,
            "name":"point1"
        }, {
            "x": 43,
            "y": 12,
            "z": 100,
            "name":"point2"
        }]
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVF8/

Comment: Thank you so much for this response - it worked a treat. Happy developer and many happy clients to come ;)

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how this can be done if the data is loaded from JSON? That is, the `function` bit can only be loaded as a string.

Comment: Oh, don't worry. The answer below solves the problem. Just need to be careful that it uses the key "format", not the key "formatter" here.

Answer (score 2):

I would create each data point as a seperate series and then leverage the dataLabels option:

```
 $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'scatter'
    },

    plotOptions: {            
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{series.name}', // make it show the name
                x: 15, // place it on right side
                y: 10
            },
        }, 
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 10
            }
        }
    },

    series: [
        {
        name: 'A',
        data: [[Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100]]
        },
        {
        name: 'B',
        data: [[Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100]]
        },
        {
        name: 'C',
        data: [[Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100]]
        },
        {
        name: 'D',
        data: [[Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100]]
        },
        {
        name: 'E',
        data: [[Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100]]
        },
        {
        name: 'F',
        data: [[Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100]]
        },
        {
        name: 'G',
        data: [[Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100]]
        }
    ]
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bGb3B/).

[image]